# Django, GET parameters keeped into the URL after a POST call

Tags: python, django, post, get, django-views

I'm new to Django!

I'm doing a simple registration form, when it is submitted, it returns a label to the previous page, that is the main page:

The form is submitted like this:

```
 <form method="post"">
```

And its mapped in urls.py:

```
url(r'^userfilt/insertForm/$', views.insertForm, name='insertForm')
```

All the urls.py file:

```
app_name = 'SSO_Management_POC'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^user/$', views.user, name='user'),
    url(r'^userfilt/$', views.userfilt, name='userfilt'),
    url(r'^userfilt/insertForm/$', views.insertForm, name='insertForm'),
    #url(r'^updateForm/$', views.updateForm, name='updateForm'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

So the related "def" its called:

```
def insertForm(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    #some stuff here     
    #sending the get parameter to the main page:
    return redirect('/SSO_Management_POC/userfilt/?label=User Registered!')
```

now when i redirect to the main page i'll see something like:
[image]

Now i want just continue working so, I'll put a filter into the input and i perform a search, below the code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        val = request.POST.get('my_textarea')
        return render(request, 'SSO_Management_POC/userfilt.html', {'top_user': TopUser.objects.filter(user_name__regex=val)})
```

As you can see is a POST call, but it comes the issue, GET parameter is still there so this cause [image]

And obviously i don't want anymore the label there, it should disappear after another call...

And the url still looks like this:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/SSO_Management_POC/userfilt/?label=User%20Registered!

Now, i know i can resolve this with workaround front end side, but i would like to know:

1. Is there something that is not good as flow of operations?
2. How can i resolve this? Where am i wrong..?
3. I tried to look for something to clean the get parameter in the url, or to reset it, beacuse i thought it was the easier way, but the only things i found costs a lot of code, have you other idea about to clean the url?
4. is there any other Django method that helps you resolve this, or maybe simply avoid this problem?

Comment: What does your `<form action="..."` look like?

Comment: I'm adding it to the question..

Comment: As I've told you before, `render` doesn't - and can't, and shouldn't - change the URL that you are on. That's simply not what it does. It's for displaying the template *of the page you have requested*.

Comment: @ivoruJavaBoy I have seen your previous question and it looks like you should read more about _views_ and _templates_, which are different things. `redirect` changes the view while `render` simply renders the same view with a different template.

Comment: Daniel now i know this... but i need to call a POST! and with the redirect i'm not able to do this! So i need or a way to call a post with the redirect, because i need to filter the result, or a way to render without keep the url... Are you able to suggest how to do it?

Comment: Daniel, its so precious your answer, but its not completed to me, you explain what i cant do, but know i can accomplish my needs: I think i totally understand the difference about render and redirect, render does not change the url because it rends same view with different template, redirect change the view!! BUT! BUT! i'm not able to make a POST call with the redirect, so how can I do two sequential POST call without avoid the append of the url (changing the url totally from the first to the second one), if render does not help and redirect cannot do the POST!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't have an `action=""` in your `form` tag which simply means that you want to post to the existing URL, including any querystring (ie. existing `GET` parameters).

Just add `action=""` to the `form` tag, such as:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'insertForm' %}">
```

Comment: Doing like this "<form method="post" action="{% url 'insertForm' %}">" it returns:  Reverse for 'insertForm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []    I'm looking at this now..

Comment: @ivoruJavaBoy Then you have a problem with your `urls.py` as it is clearly defined there, without any arguments. It is always better to use the `url` template tag; however, you can simply use `action="/SSO_Management_POC/userfilt/"` for testing purposes.

Comment: By the way i added the urls.py to the question too... it seem so simple to me!

Comment: Is that the project's main `urls.py` or the `urls.py` for an application?

Comment: Its the application one, the main one contains just this:     url(r'^SSO_Management_POC/', include('SSO_Management_POC.urls')),

Comment: Thing that i don't understand is that Daniel keeps me saying that about the difference about render and redirect, and this is clear to me, render does not change the url because it rends same view with different template, redirect change the view!! BUT! BUT! i'm not able to make a POST call with the redirect, so how can I do two sequential POST call without avoid the append of the url (changing the url totally from the first to the second one), if render does not help and redirect does not do the POST!

Comment: Did you try entering the action URL manually as in my comment above?

Comment: Yes and it works, but obviously goes directly into the user filter without executing the logic inside insertform def and i need it to be executed, so i did /SSO_Management_POC/userfilt/insertForm/ and the problem comes again, the label is always with me, and if i make a render it append to the actual url the new one, that is not correct... Guys unfortunately my problem is always the same that i ask many time, about the POST call with the redirect or a render without appending the url... it seems so strange to me how it sounds...